# Can't click the panel in KDE plasma/Kwin: how to find out what caused it and how to fix it?

Tags: debian, kde, plasma, kwin

Without any apparent reason some problems with plasma on Debian10 occurred: I can't click the bottom panel or show the main menu by pressing the windows key of my keyboard. Usually when I have problems like this I can just restart the plasmashell by running `killall plasmashell` and `kstart plasmashell` but this time this didn't solve the problem. Neither did running `killall kwin_x11` and `kwin_x11 --replace`.

What might cause these problems or rather: how to find out? (E.g. which logs should I check for which errors?) And how to resolve this problem without having to reboot?

Comment: welcome to 2k ... good question